# Can an accelerator ring be used for energy storage?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, physics, energy

Let's imagine that in the future the technological improvements allow reduce dramatically the cost of mining rare earths and producing rare earth magnets. Thanks also to a drop in the cost of tunnel construction someone decides to build a giant ring similar to a collider ring. It would use rare earth magnets instead of super conducting magnets because the synchrotron radiation would make it difficult to keep it at liquid helium temperature.

Now, the LHC can accelerate a proton to 0.999999990$c$, but reaching $c$ would need an infinite amount of energy. This giant ring would try to get much closer to $c$ putting in a huge amount of energy.

Since a proton a running in the ring is a moving charge could the energy used to accelerate it be recovered? How much could be lost due to synchrotron radiation?
Could a collider ring be use to store energy?

Comment: The ring, absolutely. The content of the ring, no chance.. The energy in the magnetic fields of the ring is several magnitudes more energy than the particle beam.

Answer (score 6):

Let me start by addressing the issue of magnets. The Large Hadron Collider, for example, [requires 1232 dipole magnets](https://home.cern/science/engineering/pulling-together-superconducting-electromagnets) generating magnetic fields of 8.3 tesla. I'm a *little* doubtful that rare earth magnets could achieve this properly; individually, they seem unable to achieve fields of more than ~1 tesla - nor are they capable of maintaining that field far enough from the magnets themselves. You could compensate for this by combining many together, but I'm not convinced that they would be adequate. I'm also not convinced that they could produce the field geometry you want, but I could be mistaken.

If we can't use rare earth magnets and have to resort to regular old superconducting magnets - well, that would kill the idea outright. These magnets have to be cooled to just 1.9 degrees above absolute zero. That costs money - and electricity. When the collider is being used, [CERN requires 200 megawatts of power](https://home.cern/science/engineering/powering-cern), i.e. roughly one-third of the power consumption of Geneva - and much of that power is *not* going into the particle beam.

Let's sidestep that particular difficulty. If you want to calculate the losses due to synchrotron radiation, the power emitted by a particle with charge $q$ and mass $m$ traveling a circular orbit with radius $r$ at an energy $E$, with a speed close to the speed of light, [is approximately](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/synchrotron.html)
$$P\approx\frac{2kq^2(E/mc^2)^4c}{3r^2}=\frac{2kq^2E^4}{3m^4c^7r^2}$$
For the LHC, setting $m$ and $q$ to be the mass of a proton, $r$ to be the LHC's radius (about 4.3 km) and $E$ to be 7 TeV, we get power a power loss per proton of $7.73\times10^{-12}$ Watts, which really isn't that bad. On the other hand, 7 TeV corresponds to about $10^{-6}$ Joules, so you're actually losing a significant amount of energy over the course of days to weeks (bearing in mind that $P$ will decrease as the particles lose energy). In short, we do have to consider energy losses - although you could mitigate this by increasing $r$ (yikes!).

Could you recover this? Well, you'd need to take into account [the spectrum of synchrotron radiation](https://www.cv.nrao.edu/%7Esransom/web/Ch5.html); higher energy particles have peak emission at higher photon energies, with an emission peak at a wavelength $\lambda_c$ that scales like
$$\lambda_c\propto\frac{1}{E^2B}$$
This could pose a challenge if you're trying to create something like a solar panel inside the beam tube - although I'd also be exceedingly worried about that solar-panel-esque device being hit by relativistic particles, as the beam isn't perfect! So perhaps a system based on directly absorbing photons would be problematic.

Finally, we have the issue of how much energy can be stored - and there are [fundamental limits to how energetic individual particles in an accelerator's beams can be](https://www.forbes.com/sites/startswithabang/2020/02/01/ask-ethan-why-cant-the-large-hadron-collider-put-more-energy-into-its-particles/?sh=1714d3834997) based on the properties of said accelerator. Higher energies require either stronger magnetic fields, larger accelerators or more particles per beam, which is presumably also limited by engineering constraints. I don't know what the ultimate limit is, but I'm sure there is one.

In short:

- I'd want to see some evidence that the rare earth approach could work.
- If you use superconducting magnets, this whole thing is not going to be efficient.
- Just using the LHC as a model, synchrotron losses become important on the timescales of days or weeks.
- Maybe you could recoup that loss, but I don't see how. Normal photon-absorbing devices would risk being damaged.

Comment: Please read the question before answering the title.

Comment: @FluidCode I've made some edits, which I hope better address your concerns. I still think that the fact that a large amount of energy would have to go into keeping the mechanism running is the overwhelming issue making the method unfeasible. I also should have explicitly said that you'll have to use superconducting magnets; I don't see a way around that.

Answer (score 2):

Let's do a coarse estimate of synchrotron radiation loss using the LHC for data points. This (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchrotron_radiation) notes "*Each proton may lose 6.7 keV per turn due to this phenomenon.*".  This (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_Hadron_Collider) says "*...11,245 revolutions per second for protons...*" and when combined with the above gives us an estimated loss of ~75.3 MeV per second per proton from synchrotron radiation.  The same link also says that the peak energy of the protons in the beam currently is ~6.5 TeV.  Now, if synchrotron energy loss were linear, the math would work out to all energy being lost in almost exactly one day, but, inconveniently for us, it isn't.  This (http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/synchrotron.html) notes that "*...This radiated energy is proportional to the fourth power of the particle speed and is inversely proportional to the square of the radius of the path. ... This means that the loss scales as the fourth power of the particle energy γmc².*", with γ being dependent on the square of the velocity.  This means most of the energy of the stored particles is radiated away pretty quickly (probably within a few hours at most) in a LHC sized ring.

Losses can be reduced by building a ring even bigger than the LHC but then you have an even more massive engineering task than building the LHC for very little gain.

So, no, it doesn't seem likely to be practical.